# Are cylinder and cone diffeomorphic?

Tags: differential-geometry, submanifold, diffeomorphism

I'm a beginner to differential geometry.
I proved the cylinder $\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3: x^2+y^2 = a\}$ for some $a>0$ and the cone $\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3: x^2+y^2 = z^2, z>0\}$ are regular surfaces. I think of some mappings between  and see that they are noninvertible at some point. Then I try to prove they are non-diffeomorphic, but cannot see how to utilize the observation.

Comment: They're not even homeomorphic. But we can try to show that cylinder and cone with its tips removed are homeomorphic/diffeomorphic.

Comment: What application did you try?

Comment: @KelvinLois: maybe I am missing something but aren't they both diffeomorphic to $S^1\times\mathbb R$? The cone defined in the OP is not the complete cone.

Comment: @Taladris Ah yes. Sorry for misread. In that case, you're correct.

Comment: @Taladris What mapping do you use to make the cone diffeomorphic to $S^1 \times \mathbb{R}$? I can only think of a trivial mapping from $S^1 \times \mathbb{R}^+$ but not $S^1 \times \mathbb{R}$

Comment: *Hint*: $\log z$ is a good idea to map to $\mathbb{R}$ factor.

Comment: @user1034138 I got it! Thank you!